# How to fix error: 'tensorflow.compat.v2.__internal__' has no attribute 'register_call_context_function'

Tags: python, tensorflow, apple-m1

Ive looked everywhere for an answer for the last week, but nothing works. I have an M1 Mac that I want to start using for reinforcement learning. I've followed some tutorials on how to get TensorFlow and Keras installed on an M1 Mac.

These are the versions that get installed:

```
Tensor Flow Version: 2.5.0
Keras Version: 2.5.0

Python 3.9.7 | packaged by conda-forge | (default, Sep  2 2021, 17:55:16) 
[Clang 11.1.0 ]
Pandas 1.3.2
Scikit-Learn 0.24.2
GPU is available
```

The problem the arises when I try to import the appropriate dependencies for the rl agent:

```
from rl.agent import DQNAgent
```

I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.compat.v2.__internal__' has no attribute 'register_call_context_function'
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Follow the following commands

```
!pip install keras-rl
from rl.agents.dqn import DQNAgent
```